# 301 Redirrects Not Working for URLs that Include ?q= in Front of the Webpage Name

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, drupal, redirect

I am moving a website from Drupal to WordPress. A lot of the website's pages are indexed in Google and Bing as http://www.example.com/?q=webpage-name I wish to redirect these pages using a 301 redirect to the new webpages that are in the format http://www.example.com/webpage-name

I tried:

```
Redirect 301 /?q=services http://www.example.com/services
```

I also tried:

```
Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/?q=services http://www.example.com/services
```

Both of the above examples redirect to the homepage not to the services page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Redirect does not consider the query string part which is why it fails, try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=services$
RewriteRule ^ /services [R=301,L]
```

You can also make a sort of catch-all thing like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```